# Zend FrameWork 2 Get ServiceLocator In Form and populate a drop down list

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to get the adapter from the form, but still could not.

In my controller I can recover the adapter using the following:

```php
// module/Users/src/Users/Controller/UsersController.php
public function getUsersTable ()
{
    if (! $this->usersTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->usersTable = $sm->get('Users\Model\UsersTable');
    }
    return $this->usersTable;
}
```

In my module I did so:

```php
// module/Users/Module.php  
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'Users\Model\UsersTable' =>  function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $uTable     = new UsersTable($dbAdapter);
                        return $uTable;
                    },
                    //I need to get this to the list of groups
                    'Users\Model\GroupsTable' =>  function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $gTable     = new GroupsTable($dbAdapter);
                        return $gTable;
                    },
            ),
    );
}
```

Could someone give me an example how to get the adapter to the table from the group form?

I have followed this example to my form users:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

**EDITED from here...**

Maybe I expressed myself wrong to ask the question.

What I really need to do is populate a select (Drop Down) with information from my table groups.

So I need to get the services inside my userForm class by ServiceLocatorAwareInterface ([see this link](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ServiceManagerAwareInterface-vs-ServiceLocatorAwareInterface-td4655675.html)) implemented because By default, the Zend Framework MVC registers an initializer That will inject into the ServiceManager instance ServiceLocatorAwareInterface Implementing any class.

After retrieving the values ​​from the table groups and populate the select.

The problem is that of all the ways that I've tried, the getServiceLocator() returns this:

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
D:\WEBSERVER\htdocs\Zend2Control\module\Users\src\Users\Form\UsersForm.php
on line 46
```

I just wanted to do this in my UserForm...

```php
namespace Users\Form;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class UsersForm extends Form implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function getServiceLocator ()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function setServiceLocator (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function __construct ($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('users');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');        

        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();

        $groups = $sm->get('Users\Model\GroupsTable')->fetchAll(); // line 46       

        $select = new Element\Select('groups');

        $options = array();

        foreach ($groups as $group) {

            $options[$group->id] = $group->name;
        }

        $select->setValueOptions($options);

        $this->add($select);

        // and more elements here...
```

Comment: hi did you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

The other various answers here generally correct, for ZF < 2.1.

Once 2.1 is out, the framework has a pretty [nice solution](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#handling-dependencies).  This more or less formalizes DrBeza's solution, ie: using an initializer, and then moving any form-bootstrapping into an init() method that is called after all dependencies have been initialized.

I've been playing with the development branch, it it works quite well.

Answer (score 6):

This is the method I used to get around that issue.

firstly, you want to make your form implement ServiceLocatorInterface  as you have done.

You will then still need to manually inject the service locator, and as the whole form is generated inside the contrstuctor you will need to inject via the contructor too (no ideal to build it all in the constructor though)

Module.php

```
/**
 * Get the service Config
 * 
 * @return array 
 */
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            /**
             * Inject ServiceLocator into our Form
             */
            'MyModule\Form\MyForm' =>  function($sm) {
                $form = new \MyModule\Form\MyFormForm('formname', $sm);
                //$form->setServiceLocator($sm);

                // Alternativly you can inject the adapter/gateway directly
                // just add a setter on your form object...
                //$form->setAdapter($sm->get('Users\Model\GroupsTable')); 

                return $form;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Now inside your controller you get your form like this:

```
// Service locator now injected
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyModule\Form\MyForm');
```

Now you will have access to the full service locator inside the form, to get hold of any other services etc such as:

```
$groups = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Users\Model\GroupsTable')->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I liked this answer the most but I found out that saving the service locator inside the form is really memory heavy, so instead of saving it inside the form for my case I would rather pass it in the constructor, use whatever I need from the config and not save it.

Comment: I'm right there with you, it is really annoying... glad to see that Zend fixed it up nicely.

Comment: Having what is just a reference inside an object isn't "memory heavy".

Comment: passing it in the constructor is no different, it's only a reference to the object you are adding, not a copy.

Comment: Nice solution, but is it really a good solution to inject service locator into the form?

Answer (score 1):

In module.php I create two services. See how I feed the adapter to the form.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'db_adapter' =>  function($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('Configuration');
                $dbAdapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db']);
                return $dbAdapter;
            },

            'my_amazing_form' => function ($sm) {
                return new \dir\Form\SomeForm($sm->get('db_adapter'));
            },

        ),
    );
}
```

In the form code I use that feed to whatever:

```
namespace ....\Form;

use Zend\Form\Factory as FormFactory;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class SomeForm extends Form
{

    public function __construct($adapter, $name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $factory = new FormFactory();

        if (null === $name) {
            $this->setName('whatever');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. I believe that now more clear to understand. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: To populate the select options just pass the model (or any other class / adapter / whatever) to the form as mentioned in my answer. Then you will be able to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

We handle this in the model, by adding a method that accepts a form

```
public function buildFormSelectOptions($form, $context = null)
{
    /** 
     * Do this this for each form element that needs options added
     */
    $model = $this->getServiceManager()->get('modelProject');

    if (empty($context)){
        $optionRecords = $model->findAll();
    } else {
        /**
         * other logic for $optionRecords
         */
    }

    $options = array('value'=>'', 'label'=>'Choose a Project');
    foreach ($optionRecords as $option) {
        $options[] = array('value'=>$option->getId(), 'label'=>$option->getName());
    }

    $form->get('project')->setAttribute('options', $options);
}
```

As the form is passed by reference, we can do something like this in the controller where the form is built:

```
    $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
    $form = $builder->createForm($myEntity);
    $myModel->buildFormSelectOptions($form, $myEntity);

    $form->add(array(
        'name' => 'submitbutton',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Submit',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));

    $form->add(array(
        'name' => 'cancel',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Cancel',
            'id' => 'cancel',
        ),
    ));
```

Note: The example assumes the base form is build via annotations, but it doesn't matter how you create the initial form.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to the other answers would be to create a ServiceManager Initializer.

An example of an existing Initializer is how the ServiceManager is injected if your instance implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.

The idea would be to create an interface that you check for in your Initialiser, this interface may look like:

```
interface FormServiceAwareInterface
{
    public function init();
    public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager);
}
```

An example of what your Initializer may look like:

```
class FormInitializer implements InitializerInterface
{
    public function initialize($instance, ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        if (!$instance instanceof FormServiceAwareInterface)
        {
            return;
        }

        $instance->setServiceManager($serviceLocator);
        $instance->init();
    }
}
```

Anything that happens in `init()` would have access to the `ServiceManager`. Of course you would need to add your initializer to your SM configuration.

It is not perfect but it works fine for my needs and can also be applied to any Fieldsets pulled from the ServiceManager.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I used get around that issue.

firstly, In Module.php, create the service (just as you have done):

```
// module/Users/Module.php  
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'Users\Model\UsersTable' =>  function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $uTable     = new UsersTable($dbAdapter);
                        return $uTable;
                    },
                    //I need to get this to the list of groups
                    'Users\Model\GroupsTable' =>  function($sm) {
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $gTable     = new GroupsTable($dbAdapter);
                        return $gTable;
                    },
            ),
    );
}
```

Then in the controller, I got a reference to the Service:

```
$users = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Test\Model\TestGroupTable')->fetchAll();
        $options = array();
        foreach ($users as $user)
           $options[$user->id] = $user->name;
        //get the form element
        $form->get('user_id')->setValueOptions($options);
```

And viola, that work.