# Handling dependencies in Zend Framework 2 Forms

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I am trying to build a form in ZF2. The problem comes when I want to populate the options array of a Select input element from a database table. A response to this question [Zend FrameWork 2 Get ServiceLocator In Form and populate a drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459180/zend-framework-2-get-servicelocator-in-form-and-populate-a-drop-down-list) by @timdev pointed me to the ZF2 docs where the 'correct' method is described. I followed this carefully but I suspect that they must have left obvious code out assuming I could fill in the gaps as I cannot get it to work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I start with a form to which I add a fieldset:

```
namespace Ctmm\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class AddPropertyForm extends Form {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct('AddProperty');

    $this->setName('addProperty');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'property',
        'type' => 'PropertyFieldset'
    ));
```

}
}

I then create the fieldset:

```
namespace Ctmm\Form;
use Ctmm\Model;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class PropertyFieldset extends Fieldset { 

public function __construct(PropertyType $property_type) {
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'property_type',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Property Type',
            'value_options' => array(
                0 => 'Detached house',
                1 => 'Semi-detached house',
                2 => 'Terraced house',
                3 => 'Bungalow',
                4 => 'Maisonette',
                5 => 'Flat',
                6 => 'Land',
                7 => 'Development Opportunity',
            ),
        ),
    ));

}
```

}

As you can see I inject PropertyType dependency into the fieldset. At this stage, I have not even used this to generate the options array. I have hard coded the array values to avoid adding another source of possible errors. Once I get the form to render I will then try to pull the array data from the PropertyType table.

Now I set up the form element manager in my Module.php:

```
namespace Ctmm;
use Ctmm\Form\PropertyFieldset;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\FormElementProviderInterface;

class Module implements FormElementProviderInterface {

public function getFormElementConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'PropertyFieldset' => function($sm) {
                $serviceLocator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                $property_type = $serviceLocator->get('Ctmm\Model\PropertyType');
                $fieldset = new PropertyFieldset($property_type);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

}

This code is straight from the docs. I have tried adding

```
return $fieldset;
```

to the PropertyFieldset factory, and I have even tried adding

```
'invokables' => array(
'PropertyFieldset' => 'Ctmm\Form\PropertyFieldset'
)
```

to the getFormElementConfig array, as well as replacing the factory with the invokable.

The last step is to create the form in my controller action using the form element manager:

```
public function addAction() {        
$formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
    $form        = $formManager->get('Ctmm\Form\AddPropertyForm');
}
```

Whatever I do, I get an error saying the Servicemanager cannot create the PropertyFieldset:

Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

File:

```
/home/mike/public_html/ctmm/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:456
```

Message:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for PropertyFieldset
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/mike/public_html/ctmm/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('PropertyFieldse...', true)
#1 /home/mike/public_html/ctmm/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Factory.php(110): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('PropertyFieldse...')
#2 /home/mike/public_html/ctmm/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Form.php(145): Zend\Form\Factory->create(Array)
#3 /home/mike/public_html/ctmm/module/Ctmm/src/Ctmm/Form/AddPropertyForm.php(33): Zend\Form\Form->add(Array)
```

Line 33 in AddPropertyForm.php is where I try to add my custom PropertyFieldset. Clearly I have an error in the fieldset itself or in the way I am declaring it. I have tried without injecting the PropertyType dependency, but that makes no difference. For completeness, the code for my PropertyType model is:

```
namespace Ctmm\Model;

class PropertyType {
public $id;
public $property_type;
protected $adapter;

public function __construct($adapter) {
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
}

public function exchangeArray($data) {
    $this->id = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->property_type = (isset($data['property_type'])) ? $data['property_type'] : null;
}

public function getPropertyType() {
    return $this->property_type;
}

public function fetchAll() {

    $sql_query = "SELECT id, property_type from property_type";
    $statement = $this->adapter->createStatement($sql_query);
    $results = $statement->execute();
    return $results;
}
```

}

Edit:

I don't have an answer but I have done some more investigation.  I created a fieldset directly in the controller to test my PropertyFieldset class and it's dependent model.

```
$property_type = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Ctmm\Model\PropertyType');
$fieldset = new PropertyFieldset($property_type);
```

This did not work immediately. First, I had to take the hinting out of the Fieldset contructor

```
public function __construct(PropertyFieldset $property_type) {
```

became

```
public function __construct($property_type) {
```

I then had to add

```
parent::__construct('propertyfieldset');
```

before it would allow me to add an element.

Once I had added these changes I was able to create a PropertyFieldset object in the controller. I could test this by var_dump()ing it.

Unfortunately, these changes to the PropertyFieldset class did not fix the basic problem, so that when I try to create the form in the controller, it generates the same error as before. I have, at least exonerated the PropertyFieldset class and it's dependent model, which says to me that I have something wrong in the getFormElementConfig() in my Module.php class

Comment: What does your AddPropertyForm factory look like? As regards to the type hinting. I think you need to use the full namespace, so: use Ctmm\Model\PropertyType; or put the full path in your constructor

Comment: I don't use a factory to create the AddPropertyForm. The form is created in the controller using the new FormElementManager. The docs insist on using this to create the form so that it picks up elements defined in the getFormElementConfig().

Comment: Just had a mess around with it and I think if you change the __construct method to init in the AddPropertyForm it should work. You will also need to return the fieldset from the factory. I will double check it all and post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I got this to work with a few minor changes:

As you noted the `PropertyFieldSet` should call the parents construct like so:

```php
parent::__construct('propertyfieldset');
```

ElementConfig should be like so:

```php
public function getFormElementConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'PropertyFieldset' => function($sm) {
                $serviceLocator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                $property_type = $serviceLocator->get('Ctmm\Model\PropertyType');
                $fieldset = new PropertyFieldset($property_type);
                return $fieldset;
            },
        )
    );
}
```

And the AddPropertyForm should be like so:

```php
namespace Ctmm\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class AddPropertyForm extends Form {

    public function init() {

        parent::__construct('AddProperty');

        $this->setName('addProperty');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'addproperty',
            'type' => 'PropertyFieldset',
        ));
    }
}
```

Instead of using __construct we use init(). This function is apparently called when instantiated by factory: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Form.Form.html#init

Regarding building the select, I would pass a TableGateway object to the fieldSet instead of a model. Then using a fetchAll function we could do the following in the form:

```php
class PropertyFieldset extends Fieldset {

    public function __construct(PropertyTypeTable $propertyTypeTable) {
        parent::__construct('propertyfieldset');


        $propertyValOpts = array();
        foreach($propertyTypeTable->fetchAll() as $propertyRow) {
            array_push($propertyValOpts,$propertyRow->property_type);
        }

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'property_type',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'attributes' => array(
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Property Type',
                'value_options' => $propertyValOpts
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Aydin, I really appreciate it. If I could give an extra +1 for the additional TableGateway advice I would.

Comment: I am trying this code, the factories works as if i do a var_dump on them they looks ok. But i can't get it to display on the form. It just gives me only blank text fields. Any clue on what can be wrong?