# Can not retrieve the object manager in the input_filter config

Tags: rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, zend-inputfilter, input-filter

I want to reuse a Fieldset that implements *InputFilterProviderInterface* o it has the method *getInputFilterSpecification* where I can declare the specifications for all the elements in the fieldset.

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'email' => array(
                'filters' => $this->getTextFilters(),
                'validators' => array(
                    $this->getUniqueObjectValidator()
...
```

The problem is that the getUniqueObjectValidator needs the *Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager* but **it is not declared in the ServiceLocator for the InputFilter**.

How do you think I can acces to the EntityManager in the inputFilter factories?

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you need to inject the `DoctrineORM EntityManager` in your `fieldset`. You could for example transfer ther `$em` from controller to form, and then from form to fieldset but this is a bad and ugly solution especialy when you have a complexe form with many fieldsets. A good solution is to take advantage from the [`Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocator`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html).

Here is a proper way handle this :

First, you have to implement the `getFormElementConfig()` function in your **Module class**. Something like this :

```
// module.php
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
return array(
    'factories' => array(
        'yourfieldset' => function ($sm) {
            $em = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
            $fieldset = new YourFieldset($em);
            return $fieldset;
        }
    )
);
}
```

Then make sure your fieldest calls the parent constructor like this :

```
parent::__construct('yourfieldset'); //with the name of the factory
```

And finaly instantiate the form via the `FormElementManager.` :

```
$formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
$form = $formManager->get('ModuleName\Form\YourForm');
```

Please see these links for more details :

- [Handling dependencies in ZF2 forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#handling-dependencies)
- [Inject DoctrineORM EntityManager in ZF2 Form](http://www.lewanscheck.de/2013/09/21/inject-doctrine-orm-entitymanager-in-zf2-form/)
- [SO : Handling dependencies in Zend Framework 2 Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448919/handling-dependencies-in-zend-framework-2-forms)
- [Howto Handle External Form Element Dependencies with FormElementManager](http://www.masterzendframework.com/zend-form/handle-external-form-element-dependencies-with-formelementmanager)